# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.localfotos.MyWallpaperService in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@456e9880

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I really, dont understand why i get this error

here is my android manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.localfotos"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

  <uses-feature android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

        <service android:name=".MyWallpaperService"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
                android:resource="@xml/livewallpaper" />

        </service>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

and the MyWallpaperService class:

```
import android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

public class MyWallpaperService extends WallpaperService {

    @Override
    public Engine onCreateEngine() {
        return new MyEngine();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public class MyEngine extends Engine {

        private MyWallpaperPainting painting;

        MyEngine() {
            SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();
            painting = new MyWallpaperPainting(holder, 
                getApplicationContext());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);
            // register listeners and callbacks here
            setTouchEventsEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            // remove listeners and callbacks here
            painting.stopPainting();
        }

        @Override
        public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
            if (visible) {
                // register listeners and callbacks here
                painting.resumePainting();
            } else {
                // remove listeners and callbacks here
                painting.pausePainting();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, 
                int width, int height) {
            super.onSurfaceChanged(holder, format, width, height);
            painting.setSurfaceSize(width, height);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            super.onSurfaceCreated(holder);
            // start painting
            painting.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            super.onSurfaceDestroyed(holder);
            boolean retry = true;
            painting.stopPainting();
            while (retry) {
                try {
                    painting.join();
                    retry = false;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset, 
                float xStep, float yStep, int xPixels, int yPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            super.onTouchEvent(event);
            painting.doTouchEvent(event);
        }

    }

}
```

thank you!

Comment: Is `MyWallpaperService` packaged within `com.localfotos`?

Comment: oh no, how i didnt see that (-:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `MyWallpaperService` is packaged in `com.localfotos`.